# Select specific values in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this ArrayList,

```
-----------------------------------------
| c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 | c6 | c7 | c8 |
-----------------------------------------
| 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  | 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  |
-----------------------------------------
```

If the user pass a String `"c5"`,
It will get the 3 siblings and itself, `c5,c6,c7,c8`.

If the user pass a String `"c7"`,
It will get the 3 siblings and itself, `c5,c6,c7,c8`.

If the user pass a String `"c3"`,
It will get the 3 siblings and itself, `c1,c2,c3,c4`.

If the user pass a String `"c1"`,
It will get the 3 siblings and itself, `c1,c2,c3,c4`.

It is like I divided the `ArrayList` with 4 values in each group.

How can I do that with only 1 `ArrayList`?

Comment: Use List.indexOf() to find the position of the target string, then calculate the lower and upper bounds of the sublist it's in, and then create a view of the original ArrayList by calling sublist() http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int)

Comment: Guava's Lists.partition() is also relevant. You could partition your list, then search each partition for the target value. http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition(java.util.List,%20int)

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

By taking index of e.g "c5" by

```
index = Integer.parseInt("c5".charAt(1)) - 1
```

After that try something like:

```
for(i = (index/4)*4;i <= (index/4)*4;i++)
    print(array[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to produce your results with this:

```
public static class KeyValuePair {
    public String Key;
    public int Value;

    public KeyValuePair(String key, int value) {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<KeyValuePair> myList;
    myList = new ArrayList<>();
    myList.add(new KeyValuePair("c1", 0));
    myList.add(new KeyValuePair("c2", 1));
    myList.add(new KeyValuePair("c3", 2));
    myList.add(new KeyValuePair("c4", 3));
    myList.add(new KeyValuePair("c5", 0));
    myList.add(new KeyValuePair("c6", 1));
    myList.add(new KeyValuePair("c7", 2));
    myList.add(new KeyValuePair("c8", 3));
    myList.add(new KeyValuePair("c9", 0));
    myList.add(new KeyValuePair("c10", 1));
    myList.add(new KeyValuePair("c11", 2));
    myList.add(new KeyValuePair("c12", 3));

    int indexLocation = -1;
    String keyToFind = "c3";
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
        if (myList.get(i).Key.contentEquals(keyToFind)) {
            indexLocation = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (indexLocation != -1) {    
        int lowerBound = indexLocation / 4 * 4;
        int upperBound = lowerBound + 4;

        for (int i = lowerBound; i < upperBound; i++) {
            System.out.println(myList.get(i).Key);
        }
    }
}
```

c3 produced the following results:

```
c1
c2
c3
c4
```

c11 produced the following results:

```
c9
c10
c11
c12
```